# programming processing, can't bind to udp port in network

Tags: udp, processing

I have a processing program working on a local machine. It reads data from a local udp port and uses this data to draw circles on my screen. It works, so that great.

But in production the program has to run on an other computer. And I cant get it to work. Processing is presenting me this error message:

```
opening socket failed!
> address:192.168.1.118, port:6666 [group:null]
> Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind
```

Of cource I checked the IP adress and these are OK as it works fine on the local machine. Here is my code for the UDP part:

```
// import UDP library
import hypermedia.net.*;

String HOST_IP = "192.168.1.118";
UDP udp;  // define the UDP object

// get an array ready 
int num = 20;
int[] xx = new int[num];
int[] yy = new int[num];


void setup() {
size(1024, 768);
smooth();
//noStroke();

// create a new datagram connection on port 6666
udp = new UDP(this, 6666, HOST_IP);
udp.listen( true );
}



//process events
void draw() {;}
/**
* To perform any action on datagram reception, you need to implement this 
* handler in your code. This method will be automatically called by the UDP 
* object each time he receive a nonnull message.
* By default, this method have just one argument (the received message as 
* byte[] array), but in addition, two arguments (representing in order the 
* sender IP address and his port) can be set like below.
*/
// void receive( byte[] data ) {       // <-- default handler
void receive( byte[] data ) {  

background(255);

// get the "real" message =
// forget the ";\n" at the end <-- !!! only for a communication with Pd !!!

 data = subset(data, 0, data.length-2);
String message = new String( data );

// print the result
println(message );
```

On both machines I use Windows XP And they are connected via a switch and udp cables.

**I don't know where to start troubleshooting and how. Any ideas?**

Comment: have you verified that on the production machine that port is available and not already in use by something else or unavailable due to firewall rules? (have you tried some other more commonly open ports like 80, 8080, 8888, 21, etc. to see whether those do work?) Also, just because it runs fine on the local machine with a local network IP doesn't mean it'll work fine on the production machine. Can that machine ping 192.168.1.118?

Comment: On both machines I have disabled the firewall. Yes, I can ping to this machine. Tried to bind to al ports mentioned (80, 8080, 21,8888). This gave the same result with the same error message.

Comment: and how are you sending data to this listener?

Comment: I am not sending anything to the UDP port. I am only listening for data that the other computer is sending to its local port 6666. I want to pickup this data.